# My dropdown menu pushes down everything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want my submenu to slide down over everything else, instead of pushing it all down. I can make this happen with `position:fixed;`, but then the size of the submenus change. How do I solve this and keep the width of the submenus?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pckyye2r/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <div id="meny">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Abcde</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Fghijklm</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>Texting texting</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav{
width: 956px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#meny{
display: table;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
}

#menu{
display: table-row;
list-style: none;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 0.9em;
}

.dropmenu{
display: table-cell;
}

.dropmenu a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ff5b2e;    
color: #303030;
}

.submenu{
display: none;
list-style: none;
background: #ff5b2e;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}

.submenu li {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.submenu li a {
width: 100%;
background: #ff5b2e;
color: #303030;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropmenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix to keep your layout. Add the following css to the `nav` class:

```
height: 20px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
```

#### JSFiddle

Comment: This works almost perfect, but my text under the menu seems to "bounce" a little when hovering the first menu option... any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

To prevent content from being pushing bottom, you must use `position: absolute;`

But that cause problems with dropdown menu width, as you are using table/table-cell structure. There is no easy way to adjust the width of dropdown menu with css, so you can use JQuery to calculate it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropmenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').stop().slideToggle().css('width', $(this).width());
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pckyye2r/2/)

Comment: + 1 nice JavaScript answer, alternatively fix the height on the menu container.

Answer (score -1):

You should style your Sub menu by positioning it `absolute`